# List all authors in in-text citation

Tags: citing, natbib

I am trying to list all the authors in my in-text citation. Currently it displays `et al.` if it is more than two authors. Please advise. Here is my code.

```
\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aomlike}
```

Here is the `aomlike` bibliography style code

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't :=   % last name first
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Comment: Is the `aomlike.bst` file available online? Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's much more helpful to post a complete compilable document rather than a code fragment. In the case of the `.bst` file, since it's not part of TeX Live it would be helpful to post a link to it. A simple fix would be to change `#2` to `#99` or whatever number of names you want to trigger the use of *et al* (untested).

Comment: @Mico yes here is the link. It is a user made file. https://github.com/stroube/AOM-TeX-style-template/blob/master/aomlike.bst

Comment: @econ_grad12345 - Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the function `format.names` in the file `aomlike.bst` may seem like the way to go, but it's not. Instead, one needs to modify the function `format.lab.names`.

I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Make a copy of `aomlike.bst` and call the copy, say, `aomlike2.bst`. (You're entirely free to choose a more descriptive name.)
- Open the file `aomlike2.bst` in a text editor. The progam you employ to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file `aomlike2.bst`, locate the definition of the function `format.lab.names`. In my copy of the file, the function definition starts on line 971 and occupies slightly less than 20 lines.
- Delete (or comment out) this function definition and replace it with the following 50-line [!] code chunk:

  ```
  FUNCTION {space.word}
  { " " swap$ * " " * }
  FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
  {'s :=
   "" 't :=
    #1 'nameptr :=
    s num.names$ 'numnames :=
    numnames 'namesleft :=
      { namesleft #0 > }
      { s nameptr
        "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
        't :=
        nameptr #1 >
          {
            nameptr #100 =
            numnames #99 > and
              { "others" 't :=
                #1 'namesleft := }
              'skip$
            if$
            namesleft #1 >
              { ", " * t * }
              {
                s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                  { 't := }
                  { pop$ }
                if$
                t "others" =
                  {
                    " " * "et~al." *
                  }
                  {
                    numnames #2 >
                      { "," * }
                      'skip$
                    if$
                    "and"
                    space.word * t *
                  }
                if$
              }
            if$
          }
          't
        if$
        nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
        namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
      }
    while$
  }
  ```
- The code truncates the list of author names shown in a citation call-out if an entry has more than 99 authors (or editors). I trust this isn't a binding restriction in practice.
- Save the file `aomlike2.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file(s) or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution. If you have no idea what the preceding sentence means, I suggest you go with option 1.
- In your main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{aomlike}` to `\bibliographystyle{aomlike2}` and perform a full recompile cycle, i.e, re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing!